# SharePoint 2007 List column of type number to have 0s prefix

Tags: list, column

May I know if there is any settings that I can set such that my column (which is of type - number) will auto insert 0s in front of the number that a user enter?

Scenario
A SharePoint 2007 List have a field - a number field. The number field allows only 5 digits of numbers - meaning that if the number field contain a number, say 136, it will display 00136. If another number, say 66, then it will display 00066.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible directly on your number column.

However you can add calculated column to your list and use formula:

```
=TEXT([YourNumberColumn],"00000")
```

Comment: Looks like calculated column is the most useful column in SharePoint, or am I wrong to say that?

Comment: It is very useful

Comment: how can I chat with you and the rest of the people in the sharepoint chatroom? I keep getting error saying my data is too old? (Can tell me which internet browser you are using - probably I can use the same browser to chat with you all) Thanks.

Comment: I am using Chrome. If you have any problems (bugs) post them on http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/